# Frame animation in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, animation, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to do frame animation and not sure should i use AnimationDrawable class for animation.
How do frame animation in Xamarin forms for Android. Is there any other approach? Simple example would be perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did trick just hiding and unhiding required elements. You could call from DoAnimation from any button click or smth else.

```
private void DoAnimation()
{
    _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    //Trigger event every second
    _timer.Interval = 1000;
    _timer.Elapsed += CheckStatus;
    //count down 5 seconds
    _countSeconds = 5000;
    _timer.Enabled = true;

}
private void SpinAnimation()
{
switch (_letterShowState) {
case SomeStateStates.State1:
    _pic1.IsVisible = false;
    _pic2.IsVisible = true;
    _pic3.IsVisible = false;
    _letterShowState = SomeStateStates.State2;
    break;
    }
    }

private void CheckStatus(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) {
    _countSeconds--;
    new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() => {
        Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
            SpinAnimation();
        });
    })).Start();

    if (_countSeconds == 0)
    {
        _timer.Stop();
    }
}
```